# What is causing this gap on the side of the screen? Bootstrap grid system

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So basically I'm just messing around here using the bootstrap system and there seems to be a small gap on the right side of the screen. There are no box shadows or anything because I saw in one or two other posts that that was causing a similar issue with people.

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width:
}

.container {
  display: table;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  background-color: #374754;
  height: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.row {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#library {
  background: blue;
}

#main {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 no-float" id="library"> library



      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-10 no-float" id="main"> main</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>footer</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

I've ripped it apart and I can't seem to figure out what's causing it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's the nature of elements inside of the `<div id="container"></div>` in Bootstrap 4 -- since your footer is outside of that you won't notice the negative margins as the answer below points out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of your CSS scripts adds `margin-left: -15px` to your `row`. That generally shifted the `div`s to the left.

And that same script adds `padding-left: 15px;` and `padding-right: 15px;`, so they don't span completely from left to right.

Comment: sorry, but no: Those are all bootstrap settings which are part of the way how bootstrap creates its layout. That's not the reason. Please see my answer below to see the real reason.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 100% width setting for `.row` - that's a bootstrap element which has its own, predefined CSS settings which you shouldn't change (except for height, maybe). This include settings for left and right margins and padding which seem strange at first sight, but which are part of the bootstrap system.

Plus you had in invalid line in your first rule for `html`, `body` and `.container` ("width: ..."), so that rule didn't apply at all.

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: table;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  background-color: #374754;
  height: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.row {
  height: 100%;
}

#library {
  background: blue;
}

#main {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 no-float" id="library"> library



      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-10 no-float" id="main"> main</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>footer</footer>

</body>

</html>
```